# сортировка std::set c++

Tags: c++, сортировка

у меня есть std::set с кастомным компаратором, в set я кладу свой тип данных, который содержит два параметра, уникальность должна обеспечиваться по первому параметру, а сортировка должна производиться по второму параметру

```
std::set<MyType, MyCastomLess> _set;

auto tmp_1 = MyType( 1, 9);
auto tmp_2 = MyType( 2, 8);
auto tmp_3 = MyType( 3, 7);
auto tmp_4 = MyType( 1, 6);
auto tmp_5 = MyType( 1, 5);
auto tmp_6 = MyType( 3, 4);
auto tmp_7 = MyType( 2, 3);

_set.insert(tmp_1 );
_set.insert(tmp_2 );
_set.insert(tmp_3 );
_set.insert(tmp_4 );
_set.insert(tmp_5 );
_set.insert(tmp_6 );
_set.insert(tmp_7 );
```

для получения первого параметра у меня есть функция get_first(), для второго get_second(). Вот сама функция less():

```
struct MyCastomLess{
bool operator()(MyType const &lhs,MyType const & rhs) const 
{
    return  (lhs->get_first() < rhs->get_first()) && (lhs->get_second() != rhs->get_second());
}
};
```

у меня никак не сортируется по второму параметру, а если я напишу вот так:

```
return  !(lhs->get_first() == rhs->get_first()) && (lhs->get_second() < rhs->get_second());
```

то в set будет отсортирован по второму параметру, но в него будут попадать переменные с одинаковым первым параметром, а это неправильно, должна быть уникальность.

я ожидаю, что на выходе, в моем set будут находиться элементы tmp_1 , tmp_2 , tmp_3, потому что после них у остальных элементов первый параметр уже не уникальный, а располагаться они там будут в таком порядке: tmp_3, tmp_2, tmp_1, так как сортироваться они должны по второму параметру, и все это в рамках одной структуры  MyCastomLess.

как мне это сделать?

Comment: “уникальность должна обеспечиваться по первому параметру, а сортировка должна производиться по второму параметру“ - что это значит?

Comment: я добавил к вопросу изменения внизу, то что я ожидаю увидеть, но никак не могу получить

Comment: Какие именно структуры данных стоит использовать зависит от того, какие операции (вставка, удаление, поиск по ключу, поиск по второму параметру, перебор всех в порядке второго параметра...) и как часто будут выполняться. Например, если перебор в порядке второго параметра делается часто, а вставка очень редко, то стоит использовать второй параметр как ключ, а при вставке проверять уникальность полным перебором.

Comment: Посмотрите `boost::multi_index` - ровно под Вашу задачу

Answer (score 4):

Если вам нужна "уникальность по первому параметру", это автоматически означает, что и сортировать ваш `std::set` вам придется именно по первому параметру. В `std::set` невозможно "оторвать" уникальность от сортировки. Не существует способа в одном `std::set` обеспечить "уникальность по первому параметру", если сортировка выполняется по второму.

Если вам упорядочение по второму нужно только "потом", то просто собираем `std::set` (или `std::unordered_set`) c уникальным первым. Затем перебрасываем все в вектор и сортируем там по второму.

Если вам упорядочение по второму нужно "на лету", то придется строить более сложную структуру данных, т.е. к основной структуре, использующей первое поле в качестве ключа (`std::set` или `std::unordered_set`), еще добавлять дополнительный индекс по второму полю (`std::multiset<MyType *>` или `std::multiset<итератор первого контейнера>`).

Например

```
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>

struct MyType
{
  unsigned first, second;
};

struct MyTypeHasherFirst
{
  size_t operator ()(const MyType &v) const
    { return std::hash<unsigned>()(v.first); }
  bool operator ()(const MyType &lhs, const MyType &rhs) const
    { return lhs.first == rhs.first; }
};

using FirstSet = std::unordered_set<MyType, MyTypeHasherFirst, MyTypeHasherFirst>;

struct MyTypeComparatorSecond
{
  bool operator ()(const FirstSet::const_iterator lhs, 
                   const FirstSet::const_iterator rhs) const
    { return lhs->second < rhs->second; }
};

using SecondSet = std::multiset<FirstSet::const_iterator, MyTypeComparatorSecond>;

int main()
{
  FirstSet first;
  SecondSet second;

  // Вставка
  MyType arr[] = 
  { 
    { 1, 9 }, { 2, 8 }, { 3, 7 }, { 1, 6 }, { 1, 5 }, { 3, 4 }, { 2, 3 } 
  };

  for (const MyType &v : arr)
    if (auto r = first.insert(v); r.second)
      second.insert(r.first);

  // Результат
  for (FirstSet::const_iterator it : second)
    std::cout << "{ " << it->first << ", " << it->second << " }" << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;

  // Вставка еще
  MyType arr2[] = 
  { 
    { 2, 5 }, { 4, 1 }, { 8, 3 }, { 1, 6 }, { 4, 4 }, { 6, 7 }, { 2, 9 } 
  };

  for (const MyType &v : arr2)
    if (auto r = first.insert(v); r.second)
      second.insert(r.first);

  // Результат
  for (FirstSet::const_iterator it : second)
    std::cout << "{ " << it->first << ", " << it->second << " }" << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: так set по дефолту сортирует по первому параметру убирая все повторения, а как сделать так, чтобы он убрал повторения по первому, но отсортировал по второму?

Comment: @user9431986: Никак не сделать. Используйте `std::set` (с сортировкой по первому) или `std::unordered_set` (с хэшированием по первому) для достижения уникальности. А затем пересортировывайте по второму самостоятельно.

Comment: а как мне пересортировать по второму потом?

Comment: я что-то не очень понял, по multiset, если честно

Comment: @user9431986: Это я не то ляпнул. Удалил.

Comment: а если сортировка нужна без создания доп контейнеров, то как можно такое сделать?
прям сразу, грубо говоря

Comment: @user9431986: "Прям сразу" одним контейнером такое эффективно реализовать не получится. Можно вручную вставлять элементы в отсортированный (по первому полю) вектор, обеспечивая уникальность первого поля. А затем, в конце, пересортировывать этот вектор по второму. Будет один контейнер. Но потребуется пересортировка.

Comment: Можно сразу вставлять в `std::multiset`, упорядоченный по второму полю. Но тогда уникальность первого поля придется проверять полным проходом по контейнеру, что неэффективно.

Comment: @user9431986 Сам я им не пользовался, но вроде как Boost.MultiIndex как раз это и делает.

Comment: хорошо, а вот я скопировал данные из set в vector, как мне теперь этот vector отсортировать по второму полю?

Comment: @user9431986: Обычный `std::sort` с предикатом сравнения по второму полю все вам отсортирует.

Comment: да, спасибо, разобрался

Comment: а как мне тогда после вектора положить эти элементы в set обратно, но уже не сортируя, так, как они лежат в векторе, просто set опять нарушит мой тонкий порядок

Comment: @user9431986: Разумеется, нарушит. Если вам нужно поддерживать порядок "на лету", то вариант с переносом в вектор - плохой. Вам нужно, как написано выше, "на лету" строить дополнительный индекс по второму полю в отдельном контейнере (`std::multiset`).

Comment: а можете по подробнее пожалуйста описать вариант с multiset, я совсем не понял

Comment: @user9431986: Добавил пример кода.

Comment: а что это за конструкция?
 if (auto r = first.insert(v); r.second)
      second.insert(r.first);

Comment: @user9431986: Это возможности `if` в С++17. Разумеется, вы можете вынести `auto r = first.insert(v);` наружу.